# acces to an object from controller to external function angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I asked this question before and i had a response telling me to add a service but it doesn't work.I want to access to a variable from a controller ($scope) in an external function you can see part of example below :

```
app.controller('formContratCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope,$cordovaFile, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaCamera) {

"$scope.owner={
"first":"john",
"last":"kennedy",
"phone":"",
"car":"",
"registration":"",
"dateRegistration":"
};


var JutoPDFCreator = {
createPDF: function(filename) {
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(13, 20, 'Prénom : '+ $scope.owner.first);
doc.text(13, 25, 'Nom : '+ $scope.owner.last);
doc.text(13, 30, 'Tél : '+ owner.phone);
doc.text(13, 35, 'véhicule loué : '+ owner.car);
doc.text(13, 40, 'Immatriculé : '+ owner.registration);
doc.text(13, 45, 'Depuis : '+ owner.dateRegistration);
.
.
}
```

Comment: And the answer, to your surprise perhaps, is to add a service again.

Comment: can you help me pls i did it like this :

Comment: in my app i did 
app.factory('formFactory', function(){

    var form = {
      proprietaire : {
  "First":"anass",
  "Last":"ettouhami",
  "Phone":"",
  "Car":"",
  "Matricule":"",
  "dateMatricule":""
}
    }
    return form;
})

and in my function 
doc.text(13, 20, 'Prénom : '+ form.owner.first);

Comment: See my answer, I added a working example too.

Comment: @skubski i saw it but it already don't work for me, I put the the service bellow the controller ,
but the function that i use is in a variable (var JutoPDFCreator: reatePDF: function(filename) {
    var doc = new jsPDF(); ....


and i don't have 
app.controller('formContratCtrl', ['myPDFService', function(myPDFService) 

but app.controller('formContratCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $cordovaFile, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaCamera) 

thank you for helping

Comment: Well I trimmed the unnecessairy variables from the 'demo'. The code will work as soon as you make sure the external library is known to the service. I think it is best to read up some javascript before you work with frameworks, because it seems you lack essential/basic javascript knowledge/concepts.

Comment: If you already asked a similar question you should have posted this to your previous question to make it evolve so people that have the same problem as yours can follow all the steps you went through to solve it. At least give a link ;)

Comment: hi, sorry but this question was asked just one time, there is no previous question about this topic thanks you for observation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a service that calls your external libary as follows:

```
app.service('myPDFService', function() {

  this.createPDF = function(filename, owner) {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(13, 20, 'Prénom : ' + owner.First);
    doc.text(13, 25, 'Nom : ' + owner.Last);
    doc.text(13, 30, 'Tél : ' + owner.phone);
    doc.text(13, 35, 'véhicule loué : ' + owner.Car);
    doc.text(13, 40, 'Immatriculé : ' + owner.registration);
    doc.text(13, 45, 'Depuis : ' + owner.dateRegistration);

    console.log(owner);
  };

});
```

The service is injected into the controller:

```
app.controller('formContratCtrl', ['myPDFService', function(myPDFService) {

  this.owner = {
    first: "John",
    last: "kennedy",
    phone: "",
    car: "",
    registration: new Date(),
    dateRegistration: new Date()
  };

  this.create = function() {
    myPDFService.createPDF('filename', this.owner);
  };

}]);
```

Here is the complete working example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LTvADrVGPZUFdIChQOLQ?p=preview). You should probably use a service to return the external library aswell, but this should get you on your way. In case the controllerAs syntax is strange and uncomprehensive , you should replace `this` with `$scope` and inject `$scope` where needed.

Angular has great documentation on services aswell. You can find it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Answer (score 0):

Just create a factory for the external lib.

```
function jsPDFFactory() {
    return function() { 
        new jsPDF() 
    };
}
angular.module('yourApp').factory('jsPDF', jsPDFFactory);
```

Then you can create your adapter like so:

```
JutoPDFCreator.$inject = ['jsPDF'];
function JutoPDFCreator = function(jsPDF) {
    this.doc = jsPDF();
 }

 JutoPDFCreator.prototype.createPDF = function(filename, owner) {
     this.doc.text(13, 20, 'Prénom : '+ owner.First);
     . . .
 }
 angular.module('yourApp').service('jutoPDFCreator', JutoPDFCreator);
```

Then just inject the jutoPDFCreator into your controller and call the createPDF() method.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, sorry im noob angular, pls how can i create a factory for an external lib ?( and which lib are you talking about ) i should add it in app.js ?
then i inject in my controller the service :
app.controller('formContratCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, $cordovaFile, $cordovaGeolocation, $cordovaCamera,jutoPDFCreator ) 

By the way i have many object in scope i have to access $scope.owner{    } , $scope.driver{    } .....

Comment: I showed you how in my answer. You have an jsPDF() lib you are using, I showed you how to create a factory for it.